# How to print out a 2d array in a certain way? (Java)

Tags: java

So here is an example text file of what I need to store into a 2d array, and print it out in certain ways.

the file contains two numbers followed by text, the numbers represent the number of rows and columns.

```
    4 4
    SOME
    FILE
    WITH
    TEXT
```

So I already stored them into an appropriate 2d array, I am just not sure how to print it out to fit this pattern:

```
    THEE
    XTLM
    EIIO
    TWFS
```

so far to print out the 2d array: i have the code:

```
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
    {
         for(int m=0;m<column;m++)
         {
              System.out.print(charArray[i][m])
          }
              System.out.println();
    }
```

I know to flip it vertically, and horizontally, by manipulating the parameters of how it is printed, but how do I manipulate the parameters so that it will print like the above? THanks so much

The text file would look exactly like above, called txt1.txt.... and I am going to use 4 of them. IT looks exactly like the example listed above:

```
    4 4

    Some 
    File 
    With
    Text
```

my goal is to just store them in a 2d array, and manipulate how I print them. I already know how to manipulate it in some ways but just not in the pattern also listed above. THanks guys! :)

Comment: Smells like homework.

Comment: @RaviU Does it matter?

Comment: Basically it prints them column wise (reverse order) starting from the last column...so manipulate your indices to reflect this...

Comment: He's made an attempt at the code. Perhaps if he does the `for` loop from `row-1` down to `0`, and likewise for column, it might work better... ;)

Comment: @RaviU - It is not like he is asking for code without doing anything...he is just asking for pointers and he has already showed what he tried...so quit whining.

Comment: You are accessing `charArray[a][b]` but neither `a` nor `b` is defined =/.

Comment: @DerekYee Happy to help. And for anyone downvoting my answer, that's fine and I respect your right to do that, but I personally subscribe to the philosophy here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255853/should-downvotes-be-used-to-punish-people-who-answer-bad-questions

Comment: @nhouser9 I doubt people downvote your answer because the question is bad.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You want to start with the last element in the last column, and go backwards by columns first. So all you need to do is change the direction and order of your loops:

```
for(int m=column - 1;m>=0;m--) {
    for(int i=row - 1;i>=0;i--) {
        System.out.print(charArray[i][m])
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```